# Ons-Lazy-Repeat Calculate Item's Height

Tags: onsen-ui

I have a list of results with images and line text that varies in word length. It will most of the time exceed items list row height with ons-lazy-repeat. How can I make use of calculateItemHeight to adjust the height that varies accordingly? I've searched basically online for days but it seems there's not much documentation for it, nor anyone that has raised or facing the same issue as me :(

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?